# Problems with running sql on Jupyter

Tags: python, sql, jupyter

Why can't I get results with the following code? Without the first line it worked.

```
%%sql
DESCRIBE user

SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE state IN ("NC", "NY");
```

Comment: What happens instead of getting results? Is there an error message?

Comment: you might missing a ; behind DESCRIBE user